# JS Pagination Using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm attempting to make an API call using promises. The API is paginated and as such, depending on the headers in that first API call make more to get the rest of the results if need be.

Here's what I have so far:

```
const get = (url, pageNo) => {
    var options = {
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Token token=${apiToken}`
        },
        json: true,
        page: pageNo
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(options, (err, resp) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(resp);
        })
    });
};
```

Using `get()` to loop and get all responses:

```
const getAll = (plannerId, timestamp, range) => {
    const plannerBookingsUrl = new URL(
        `/api/planners/${plannerId}/bookings?since=${timestamp}&range=${range}`,
        baseUrl
    );

    let response = get(plannerBookingsUrl, 1);
    let bookings = [];
    bookings.push(response);

    response.then(results => {
        let moreRequests = true;
        let currentPage = 1;
        const totalPages = parseInt(results.headers['x-total-pages']);

        while (moreRequests) {
            if (currentPage < totalPages) {
                nextBatch = get(plannerBookingsUrl, currentPage + 1);
                bookings.push(nextBatch);
                currentPage++;
            } else {
                moreRequests = false;
            }
        }
    });

    return Promise.all(bookings);
};
```

`Main()` where I'm using `getAll(...)`:

```
const main = () => {
    const response = getAll(
        '11716',
        '2020-02-27',
        '7'
    );

    response.then(results => {
        console.log(results);
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
};

main();
```

This returns the initial promise but not the remaining promises.

What I'm really have a problem with is reading the first API, making the remainder and returning them all together to be using in my main function.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What API are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could put all your fetching logic inside the `while` loop. The way you get your bookings is the same, except for the first time where you need to get a little more information on the amount of pages.

Accomplish this by making your function `async` and check the first time of the loop if the `totalPages` value is already known. If it's not, `await` the response and get the info from the headers, and otherwise just push the response to the `bookings` array.

```js
const getAll = async (plannerId, timestamp, range) => {

    const plannerBookingsUrl = new URL(
        `/api/planners/${plannerId}/bookings?since=${timestamp}&range=${range}`,
        baseUrl
    );

    let bookings = [];
    let currentPage = 1;
    let totalPages = null;

    while (totalPages === null || currentPage < totalPages) {
        let response = get(plannerBookingsUrl, currentPage);
        if (totalPages === null) {
            let results = await response;
            totalPages = parseInt(results.headers['x-total-pages']);
        }
        bookings.push(response);
        currentPage++;
    }

    return Promise.all(bookings);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning `Promise.all(bookings)` outside `response.then` callback, so at this point `bookings` contains only the first call `get(plannerBookingsUrl, 1)`.

Here is a possible solution using `async`:

```
const getAll = async (plannerId, timestamp, range) => {
    const plannerBookingsUrl = new URL(
        `/api/planners/${plannerId}/bookings?since=${timestamp}&range=${range}`,
        baseUrl
    );

    let response = get(plannerBookingsUrl, 1);
    let bookings = [];
    bookings.push(response);

    const results = await response; // wait for results here

    let moreRequests = true;
    let currentPage = 1;
    const totalPages = parseInt(results.headers['x-total-pages']);

    while (moreRequests) {
        if (currentPage < totalPages) {
            nextBatch = get(plannerBookingsUrl, currentPage + 1);
            bookings.push(nextBatch);
            currentPage++;
        } else {
            moreRequests = false;
        }
    }

    return Promise.all(bookings); // bookings now contains every next batch
};
```

adapt on `main()` function:

```js
const main = async () => {
    const results = await getAll(
        '11716',
        '2020-02-27',
        '7'
    );

    ...
};

main();
```